# Stringify object that has special characters in javascript

Tags: php, jquery

I have object that you can see in following image.

[image]

I am trying to pass this object to another js function. As I can not directly pass object so first I am converting it into json like following.

```
var str = '<tr onmouseover="diamond_information('+JSON.stringify(main_arr[i])+');">';
```

**I got following json. It created problem where I had special characters.**

[image]

When I mouse over tr tag then I got following error.

> SyntaxError: invalid property id

What could be the correct way of passing object to function or how to stringfy object that has special charaters? After Spending many hours on it. Now I am not getting any solution so any suggections?

Comment: Please post a small [mcve] with an example of the JSON

Comment: I edited my question and tried to make some improvements.

Comment: why do you need all that json stringified into the html in the first place?

Comment: I have a object that I am trying to stringify because on mouse over I have to show information on right sidebar and in popup. There are total 90 columns in tables that I am managing

Comment: You need to completely rethink. you do NOT want such a string in the HTML. Leave the JSON as a JavaScript object in script and tell which one to use in the mouseover

Answer (score 1):

No need to print all that  json in the html. Just pass the array reference and index to the function and do whatever you need to with that object inside the function.

```
var str = '<tr onmouseover="diamond_information(main_arr, '+ i +');">';
```

JS

```
function diamond_information(arr, index){
   console.log(arr[index]);
}
```

Comment: I have like, for (var i = 0; i < main_arr.length; i++) { echo main_arr[i].Brand; } when I used your syntax it gave me "SyntaxError: missing ] after element list" and in console it looks like "diamond_information([object Object]"

Comment: javascript has no `echo`, is that php? And no idea where you run into syntax error. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: sorry my mistake, I am using it like main_arr[i].Brand, there is no php in it